# List potential applications that could open a file

Tags: macos, cocoa, launch-services

Is it possible to get a list of applications installed on the users computer that could be used to open a file (in my case an image), similar to the list shown through the Finder's "Open With..." menu?

Comment: To clarify.. I was looking for a scripting Cocoa/Carbon solution. Thank's Rob!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you looking for a programatic or scripting solution? Programatically, look at [Launch Services](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/LaunchServicesConcepts/LSCIntro/LSCIntro.html) (`LSCopyAllRoleHandlersForContentType()` for instance). For scripting, you probably want `lsregister` which is buried down in

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support
```

Don't let its location in the docs fool you. It in the Carbon docs, but it's actually CoreServices, which is not deprecated.

Comment: I've found LSCopyApplicationURLsForURL() to be more useful, because it includes Carbon applications as well as Cocoa. 

When inspecting a jpeg file LSCopyAllRoleHandlersForContentType() was returning about 7 app identifiers, whereas LSCopyApplicationURLsForURL() found 27.