# Get the list of applications which can open a file in Mac OS X

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, filesystems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List potential applications that could open a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051735/list-potential-applications-that-could-open-a-file)

How can I get the list of applications registered to open a specific file (from its path) under Mac OS X, in objective-C?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051735/list-potential-applications-that-could-open-a-file .

Answer (score 5):

[Launch Services Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/LaunchServicesConcepts/LSCIntro/LSCIntro.html) has the information you need.  But basically you can get that list multiple ways.  If you have the URL to the file, you would use [LSCopyApplicationURLsForURL](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/LaunchServicesReference/Reference/reference.html).

For example: `LSCopyApplicationURLsForURL(fileURL, kLSRolesViewer | kLSRolesEditor);`